# Possible to stub method twice within a single test to return different results?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I would like to re-stub `someHandler.getStatus`, but I'm getting `TypeError: Attempted to wrap getStatus which is already wrapped` ..

```
it('is a test', function() {

  sandbox.stub(someHandler, 'getStatus', function(callback) {
    callback(null, {
      value: 1
    });
  });

  sandbox.stub(someOtherHandler, 'doSomething', function(callback) {
    callback(null);
  });

  sandbox.stub(someHandler, 'getStatus', function(callback) {
    callback(null, {
      value: 0
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Sinon has a nice API for handling multiple calls `(stub.onCall(n);)` to the same stubbed method.

Example from [stub api doc](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs):

```
"test should stub method differently on consecutive calls": function () {
    var callback = sinon.stub();
    callback.onCall(0).returns(1);
    callback.onCall(1).returns(2);
    callback.returns(3);

    callback(); // Returns 1
    callback(); // Returns 2
    callback(); // All following calls return 3
}
```

You can also use `onFirstCall()` , `onSecondCall()`, and `onThirdCall()`.

We are using this approach extensively in our tests.

Answer (score 1):

try tracking the calls using an external variable.  first time it's called, return the first value and increment the counter. second call (and all subsequent calls), return the second value.

```
it('is a test', function() {

  let callCount = 0

  sandbox.stub(someHandler, 'getStatus', function(callback) {
    callback(null, {
      value: callCount++ == 0 ? 1 : 0
    });
  });

  sandbox.stub(someOtherHandler, 'doSomething', function(callback) {
    callback(null);
  });    
});
```

this is a simple example to handle 2 calls, but you expand it to handle multiple calls if needed.

Comment: `sinon stub(obj, 'meth', fn) has been removed, see documentation`. This current syntax will do the same thing as above: `sandbox.stub(someHandler, 'getStatus').callsFake(() => callCount++ == 0 ? 1 : 0);`.