# Sinon: how to create a stub that resolves multiple calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

It seems straightforward to create a stub that returns different values on repeated calls:
[Possible to stub method twice within a single test to return different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404854/possible-to-stub-method-twice-within-a-single-test-to-return-different-results)

But, I how does one do this with an **async** method that resolves on multiple calls?

```
sinon(module, "myFunction")
  .resolves('a')
  .resolves('b')
```

To be clear, in the fragment above, the second resolves overwrites the first, so it always returns 'b'.   I'd like the behavior where 'myFunction' first resolves 'a' and then resolves 'b'.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the solution:

```
sinon(module, "myFunction")
  .onFirstCall().resolves('a')
  .onSecondCall().resolves('b')
```